# Display selected attribute value in else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below I am looking through a list of swatches and assigning the title attribute to variable and then displaying this value below the swatch.

On mouseleave if the parent has selected class I return false so that the title attribute value is still shown. However if I mouseleave from swatch where parent does not have selected class the title attribute value becomes empty as shown in the code.

How do I modify so that on mouseleave if parent does not have selected class, it uses the title attribute value from the parent selected class?

```js
$('.producttile_swatches .swatches ul li span.swatch_color').each(function(){ 
    $(this).mouseenter(function(){
        var swatchColor = $(this);
        var swatchTitle = swatchColor.attr('title');
        var swatchTitleInsert = swatchColor.closest('.carousel').next();
        swatchTitleInsert.html(swatchTitle);

        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            if($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')){
                return false;
            } else {
                //I want to display title attr value from parent selected//
                swatchTitleInsert.html(''); 
            }
        });     
    });
});
```

```css
span {display:block;margin-bottom:10px;width:50px;height:50px;background:#ccc;}
.swatch-title-insert {width:300px;height:50px;background:blue;color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel producttile_swatches">
  <div class="swatches">
    <ul>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#" class="selected">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="red"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="white"></span>
        </a>   
      </li>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="blue"></span>
        </a>   
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="swatch-title-insert"></div>

<div class="carousel producttile_swatches">
  <div class="swatches">
    <ul>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="red"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#" class="selected">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="white"></span>
        </a>   
      </li>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="blue"></span>
        </a>   
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="swatch-title-insert"></div>

<div class="carousel producttile_swatches">
  <div class="swatches">
    <ul>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="red"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="white"></span>
        </a>   
      </li>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#" class="selected">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="blue"></span>
        </a>   
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="swatch-title-insert"></div>
```

Comment: a working snippet or fiddle will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your answer:

```js
$('.producttile_swatches .swatches ul li span.swatch_color').each(function(){
  var swatchColor = $(this);
  var swatchTitle = swatchColor.attr('title');
  var swatchTitleInsert = swatchColor.closest('.carousel').next(); 
  $(this).mouseenter(function(){
    swatchTitleInsert.html(swatchTitle);   
    $(this).mouseleave(function(){
      if($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')){
        return false;
      } else {
        var swatchTitle = $(this).closest('.producttile_swatches').find('.swatches ul li a.selected span.swatch_color').attr('title');
        swatchTitleInsert.html(swatchTitle); 
      }
    });     
  });
});
```

```css
span {display:block;margin-bottom:10px;width:50px;height:50px;background:#ccc;}
.swatch-title-insert {width:300px;height:50px;background:blue;color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel producttile_swatches">
  <div class="swatches">
    <ul>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#" class="selected">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="red"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="white"></span>
        </a>   
      </li>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="blue"></span>
        </a>   
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="swatch-title-insert"></div>

<div class="carousel producttile_swatches">
  <div class="swatches">
    <ul>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="red"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#" class="selected">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="white"></span>
        </a>   
      </li>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="blue"></span>
        </a>   
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="swatch-title-insert"></div>

<div class="carousel producttile_swatches">
  <div class="swatches">
    <ul>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="red"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="white"></span>
        </a>   
      </li>
      <li class="product_swatch_list_item">
        <a href="#" class="selected">
          <span class="swatch_color" title="blue"></span>
        </a>   
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="swatch-title-insert"></div>
```

Comment: @Jgunzblazin use `$(this).parent().siblings('.selected')` and `return false;`. if does not work, get me your fiddle link please.

Comment: @Jgunzblazin I think this is your answer: https://jsfiddle.net/c62Lz7hv/22/

Comment: @Jgunzblazin is not this the solution?

Comment: I am simplifying your code, I moved the variables so they were global: https://jsfiddle.net/c62Lz7hv/25/

Comment: @Jgunzblazin by delete the variables from .mouseleave event handler function, the code does not work as you want.

Comment: see this fiddle.If there are multiple instances of the producttiles it does not work..how do I modify so it works for each one only? 
https://jsfiddle.net/c62Lz7hv/28/

Comment: @Jgunzblazin please check fiddle /30

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jgunzblazin My pleasure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167489/discussion-between-seyed-morteza-and-jgunzblazin).